# How to update version of a javascript file in all forms in visual studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, webforms

I am developing a web application. I am using a main javascript file that is used in most of the forms.

```
<script src="assets/public.js"></script>
```

This file is being updated regularly and the users can't get the last updated file because the old file is cached with browser. So I am using a version indicator at the end of the file name to enforce browsers to use the latest version of my javascript file  :

```
<script src="assets/public.js?version=54"></script>
```

I should update the version in every form after each change in the javascript file. this is a manual task which is really time-consuming and some forms might be missed to update.

Is there any effective way to define the last version as a constant and automatically update all forms regarding the last version?

Comment: how are you developing the app? If you are including the common scripts on every page and not using templates then that itself is bad practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to use the last modified date of the file as the version indicator. So even no need to define constant.

```
<script src="asset/public.js?version={{lastModifiedDate('asset/public.js')}}"></script>
```

Below function returns the last modified date of file:

```
function lastModifiedDate(url) {
        try {
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open("HEAD", url, false);
            req.send(null);
            if (req.status == 200) {
                return req.getResponseHeader('Last-Modified');
            }
            else return false;
        } catch (er) {
            return er.message;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your project you need to have a folder [App_Start] there in the [BundleConfig.cs] file you can register bundles:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                       "~/Scripts/public-{version}.js"));
```

and in the view add this:

```
<head>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/public")
</head>
```

Every time when change .js version update variable {version} from the file [BundleConfig.cs]